# Jquery IMG src selection from XML Node

Tags: jquery, xml

Can anyone advise whether it would be possible to pull the image src for each image from an RSS feed node containing html?

http://news.google.co.uk/news?ds=n&pq=news+pop&hl=en&sugexp=gsis,i18n%3Dtrue&cp=5&gs_id=34&xhr=t&q=music+pop&client=firefox-a&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&gs_upl=&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&biw=1440&bih=681&um=1&ie=UTF-8&output=rss

We basically want to list the stories from a Google rss feed, I can access the descriptions/links etc as they are within their own nodes - but cannot access the individual images.

Any advice gratefully received

This is my code - 
    $(function(){
    $.get('rss.php',{feed_url:'http://news.google.co.uk/news?ds=n&pq=pop+musicnews&hl=en&sugexp=gsis,i18n%3Dtrue&cp=9&gs_id=36&xhr=t&q=pop+music&gs_upl=&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&biw=1440&bih=681&bs=1&um=1&ie=UTF-8&output=rss'},function(xml){ //Grab rss.php, enter in the GET feed_url attribute and set it to the URL of the feed you want.

```
    $(xml).find("item").each(function() {

        var i = $(xml).find("item").index(this);

        var desc = $('item: description',xml).replace(/&quot;/, '"');

        if(i < 2) {
                var newsTitleOne = $('item:eq(0) title',xml).text();
                var newsTitleTwo = $('item:eq(1) title',xml).text();
                $(".newsIOne .newsText .t").append(newsTitleOne);
                $(".newsITwo .newsText .t").append(newsTitleTwo);
                alert(hello);
        } else {
            $("ul").append("<li style='color: blue'>" + $(this).text() + "</li>");
        }
    });




});
```

});

Cheers
Paul

Answer (score 0):

In javascript you can read data from any type of textual data, you just need the right parse or pacience to do it. For XML it's easy since it is suited to handle XML natively, XML is the base of HTML.

Using jQuery would be alot easier, see the example bellow.

```js
var xml = "<rss version='2.0'><channel><title>RSS Title</title></channel></rss>",
    xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml ),
    $xml = $( xmlDoc ),
    $title = $xml.find( "title" );
```

More info can be found on [jQuery.parseXML() - jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/).

For the feed u posted it will be trickier, because the image is in the description HTML encoded.

But the HTML can be decoded by doing this.

```js
var decoded = description
   .replace(/&amp;/g,'&')
   .replace(/&lt;/g,'<')
   .replace(/&gt;/g,'>')
   .replace(/&quot;/, '"');
```

So you parse the feed, obtain the description, decode it and parse the decription again, that way you the `img` element.
If this is overkill for you and just what the image source use Regex to extract it.

```js
/(?: src=&quot;)(.+)(?:&quot;)/
```

Something like this will do the job.

Given your example it will something like this.

```js
function (xml) { 

     var items = $(xml).find('item');
     for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {

         var description = items.eq(i).find('description');


         //Alternative 1
         var descElem = $.parseXML(
             description
             .replace(/&amp;/g, '&')
             .replace(/&lt;/g, '<')
             .replace(/&gt;/g, '>')
             .replace(/&quot;/, '"')
         );
         var imgSrc = $(descElem).find('img').attr('src');


         //Alternative 2
         var imgSrc = /(?: src=&quot;)(.+)(?:&quot;)/.exec(descrition); 
         //null if don't exist

         (...)
     }

 }
```

Comment: cheers for your help, bit lost with applying the actual .replace though! I've included my code above - how would I apply a regular expression/ .replace to the description variable?  Cheers Paul

Comment: Just added a code example with the alternatives, didn't tested but it'll be something like that.